# AddListItem is not populating the List in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jsom, spservices

I have a knowledge check in HTML form, so I cant inject into CEWP or SP pages. It needs to be JS, CSS, and HTML. How do I populate a list if someone completes a Knowledge Check? It will add the score, module#, name, and date to list 'JAcerts' upon completion.

Here is my check: https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/6gkL92av/6/

This line needs to be the action where I submit, I think? When the cert taker hits this button I need their info to go to the list, 'JAcerts'.

```
 <a id="btn" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='#game-over'">Next</a>
```

[image]

**Check out my js in my jsfiddle. I HAVE TRIED so many JS codes but not connecting them correctly.**

The list and Knowledge check are in the same site "/sites/OA03/Lists/JAcerts'" for the list and "sites/OA03/JA%20Training/" for Knowledge Check.

****UPDATE**** - I did AddListItem but it is not populating:

```
  if (window.location.href === "JATrainingModule.html"){
      document.getElementById("cert5").style.display = 'block';
   }

   var thisUserAccount ;          
   var login;
   $(document).ready(function() {
    thisUserAccount= $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
    });

    if(thisUserAccount) {
        var pair = thisUserAccount.split("\\");
        login = pair[1];
    }
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = login;
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d;
        $("#finalbtn").click(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AddListItem, "sp.js");
   });
  });



  function AddListItem() {
        var q1Val,q2Val,q3Val,q4Val,q5Val,q6Val;
        var q1Answer =  $("input[name='yes-1']:checked")[0];
        var q2Answer =  $("input[name='no-2']:checked")[0];
        var q3Answer =  $("input[name='no-3']:checked")[0];
        var q4Answer =  $("input[name='no-4']:checked")[0];
        var q5Answer =  $("input[name='no-5']:checked")[0];
        var q6Answer =  $("input[name='yes-6']:checked")[0];
        var score =  0;
        if(q1Answer.classList.contains("one-a")){
            q1Val = "Correct - "+ 
   q1Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q1Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
  q1Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        if(q2Answer.classList.contains("two-c")){
            q2Val = "Correct - "+ 
    q2Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q2Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
   q2Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        if(q3Answer.classList.contains("three-d")){
            q3Val = "Correct - "+ 
    q3Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q3Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
     q3Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        if(q4Answer.classList.contains("four-b")){
            q4Val = "Correct - "+ 
    q4Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q4Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
    q4Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        if(q5Answer.classList.contains("five-a")){
            q5Val = "Correct - "+ 
     q5Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q5Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
    q5Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        if(q6Answer.classList.contains("six-d")){
            q6Val = "Correct - "+ 
   q6Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-');
            score += 10;
        }else{
            q6Val = "Incorrect - "+ 
    q6Answer.nextElementSibling.innerText.replace('\n','-')
        }
        var listTitle = "JAcerts";
        //Get the current client context
        //context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        new 
   SP.ClientContext("https://-------.----.---.---.---/sites/OA03/");

        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        //Create a new record
        var listItemCreationInformation = new 
    SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var listItem = list.addItem(listItemCreationInformation);
        //Set the values
        /*listItem.set_item("Title", login);
        listItem.set_item("Module", 'Module 1');
        listItem.set_item("Q1", q1Val);
        listItem.set_item("Q2", q2Val);
        listItem.set_item("Q3", q3Val);
        listItem.set_item("Q4", q4Val);
        listItem.set_item("Q5", q5Val);
        listItem.set_item("Q6", q6Val);*/
        listItem.set_item("Title", login); 
        listItem.set_item("Module", 'Module 1'); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_1", q1Val); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_2", q2Val); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_3", q3Val); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_4", q4Val); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_5", q5Val); 
        listItem.set_item("_x0051_6", q6Val);
        
        listItem.set_item("Score", score);

        listItem.update();
        context.load(listItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
       this.AddListItemSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, 
        this.AddListItemFailed));
    }

    function AddListItemSucceeded() {
        alert('Saved Successfully!');
    }

    function AddListItemFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + 
   args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Comment: Where are you going to host your HTML/JS solution? In SharePoint? Or in a different platform?

Comment: SP2013 environment.

Answer (score 1):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a **Web Part Page**

2.Add a **Script Editor** web part

3.Paste the below code:

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Add Items to Test77</h2>
<div id="AddListData">
    <div>
    
        Title:
        <br/>
            <input type="text" id="txtTitle" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
    
        Module:
        <br/>
            <input type="text" id="txtModule" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
    
        Score:
        <br/>
            <input type="text" id="txtScore" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
 
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

**JSON:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
$(function(){
 
    bindButtonClick();
 
});
 
function bindButtonClick() {
 
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function() {
 
        addListItem();
 
    });
 
}
 
function addListItem() {
 
    var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
 
    var module = $("#txtModule").val();
 
    var score = $("#txtScore").val();
 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test77');
 
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 
    oListItem.set_item('Title', title);
 
    oListItem.set_item('Module', module);
 
    oListItem.set_item('Score', score);
 
    oListItem.update();
 
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddSucceeded),
 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddFailed)
 
    );
 
}
 
function onAddSucceeded(sender, args) {
 
    $("#divResult").html("Item successfully added!");
 
}
 
function onAddFailed(sender, args) {
 
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
 
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 
}
 
</script>
```

[image]